# Getting the set of nodes connected till the main parent node in R

Tags: r

I have a data set which has 6 rows and 3 columns. The first column represents children, whereas second column onward immediate parents of the corresponding child is allocated. [image]

Above, one can see that "a" and "b" don't have any parents. whereas "c" has only parent and that is "a". "d" has parents "b" and "c" and so on.

What I need is: if given the input as the child, it should give me all the ancestors of that child including child.

e.g. "f" is the child I chose then desired output should be :
{"f", "d", "b"}, {"f", "d", "c", "a"}, {"f", "e", "b"}, {"f", "e", "c", "a"}.

Note: Order of the nodes does not matter.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It would help if you gave us code with data - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Bulat, I am asking for the code. And that image file is the data.

Comment: data for reproducible example would be : `d <- data.frame(list("c" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
          "p1" = c(NA, NA, "a", "b", "b", "d"), 
          "p2" = c(NA, NA, NA, "c", "c", "e")))`

Comment: @Bulat, yes. actually I didn't think it that way as I was importing it from excel.

Comment: You probably want to look into the `igraph` package if you are going to be doing a lot of things with trees and graph networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive function that makes all possible family lines:

```
d <- data.frame(list("c" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
      "p1" = c(NA, NA, "a", "b", "b", "d"), 
      "p2" = c(NA, NA, NA, "c", "c", "e")), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Make data more convenient for the task.
library(reshape2)
dp <-  melt(d, id = c("c"), value.name = "p") 

# Recursive function builds ancestor vectors.
getAncestors <- function(data, x, ancestors = list(x)) {

  parents <- subset(data, c %in% x & !is.na(p), select = c("c", "p"))

  if(nrow(parents) == 0) {
    return(ancestors)
  }

  x.c <- parents$c
  p.c <- parents$p

  ancestors <- lapply(ancestors, function(x) {
    if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)

    # Here we want to repeat ancestor chain for each new parent.
    res <- list()
    matches <- 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(parents)) {
      if (tail(x, 1) == parents[i, ]$c){
       res[[i]] <- c(x, parents[i, ]$p)
       matches <- matches + 1
      }
    }

    if (matches == 0) { # There are no more parents. 
      res[[1]] <- x
    }

    return (res)
  })

  # remove one level of lists.
  ancestors <- unlist(ancestors, recursive = F)

  res <- getAncestors(data, p.c, ancestors)
  return (res)

}

# Demo of results for the lowest level.
res <- getAncestors(dp, "f")
res
#[[1]]
#[1] "f" "d" "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "f" "d" "c" "a"

#[[3]]
#[1] "f" "e" "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "f" "e" "c" "a"
```

You will need to implement this in a similar way through recursion or with a while loop.

Comment: can you please tell me where do have to make changes for getting the output. I have been trying ever since you gave me the approach but not able to success.

Comment: @Artiga I think I have managed to make it work per your description

Comment: This is really elegant solution. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create sample data. Note use of `stringsAsFactors` here, I'm assuming your data are characters and not factors:

```
> d <- data.frame(list("c" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), "p1" = c(NA, NA, "a", "b", "b", "d"), "p2" = c(NA, NA, NA, "c", "c", "e")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

First tidy it up - make the data long, not wide, with each row being a child-parent pair:

```
> pairs = subset(reshape2::melt(d,id.vars="c",value.name="parent"), !is.na(parent))[,c("c","parent")]
> pairs
   c parent
3  c      a
4  d      b
5  e      b
6  f      d
10 d      c
11 e      c
12 f      e
```

Now we can make a graph of the parent-child relationships. This is a *directed* graph, so plots child-parent as an arrow:

```
> g = graph.data.frame(pairs)
> plot(g)
```

[image]

Now I'm not sure exactly what you want, but `igraph` functions can do anything... So for example, here's a search of the graph starting at `d` from which we can get various bits of information:

```
> d_search = bfs(g,"d",neimode="out", unreachable=FALSE, order=TRUE, dist=TRUE)
```

First, which nodes are ancestors of `d`? Its the ones that can be reached from `d` via the exhaustive (here, breadth-first) search:

```
> d_search$order
+ 6/6 vertices, named:
[1] d    c    b    a    <NA> <NA>
```

Note it includes `d` as well. Trivial enough to drop from this list. That gives you the set of ancestors of `d` which is what you asked for.

What is the relationship of those nodes to `d`?

```
> d_search$dist
  c   d   e   f   a   b 
  1   0 NaN NaN   2   1
```

We see that `e` and `f` are unreachable, so are not ancestors of `d`. `c` and `b` are direct parents, and `a` is a grandparent. You can check this from the graph.

You can also get all the paths from any child upwards using functions like `shortest_paths` and so on.